# How to get half hour if exist with mysql hour function

Tags: mysql

I want to get 8:30 hour instead of 8 from below query

```
   HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2018-12-01 07:00:00','2018-12-01 15:30:00')
```

Mysql hour function only return number of hour not half hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the difference between two datetime values in `SECOND` units, using [`TimeStampDiff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function. Now, we can convert this into Time using [`Sec_To_time()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) function.

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2018-12-01 07:00:00','2018-12-01 15:30:00'))
```

**Result**

```
| SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2018-12-01 07:00:00','2018-12-01 15:30:00')) |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 08:30:00                                                                        |
```

Answer (score 0):

You may call both `HOUR` *and* `MINUTE`, the latter to get the minute component:

```
SELECT
    HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2018-12-01 07:00:00','2018-12-01 15:30:00')) +
    MINUTE(TIMEDIFF('2018-12-01 07:00:00','2018-12-01 15:30:00')) / 60.0 AS hours
FROM yourTable;
```

This outputs `8.5` for the number of hours.

Another option would be to first convert both timestamps to UNIX timestamps in seconds since epoch.  Then convert their difference back to hours:

```
SELECT
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-12-01 15:30:00') -
     UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-12-01 07:00:00')) / 3600.0 AS hours
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo